# How to write line by line in file using buffered writer?

Tags: java, file, filewriter, bufferedwriter

Here is my code to write the text in file line by line

```
public class TestBufferedWriter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // below line will be coming from user and can vary in length. It's just an example
        String data = "I will write this String to File in Java"; 
        int noOfLines = 100000;

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        writeUsingBufferedWriter(data, noOfLines);
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = stopTime - startTime;
        System.out.println(elapsedTime);
        System.out.println("process end");

    }


    private static void writeUsingBufferedWriter(String data, int noOfLines) {
        File file = new File("C:/testFile/BufferedWriter.txt");
        FileWriter fr = null;
        BufferedWriter br = null;
        String dataWithNewLine=data+System.getProperty("line.separator");
        try{
            fr = new FileWriter(file);
            br = new BufferedWriter(fr);
            for(int i = 0; i<noOfLines; i++){
                br.write(dataWithNewLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            try {
                br.close();
                fr.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

But its writing multiple lines(using 8192 buffer size) in one go , instead of writing one line at a time ? Not sure what I am missing here ?

Comment: Also: use try-with-resources instead of closing the streams manually.

Comment: Could you comment on what do you think *Buffered*Writer means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could call `br.flush()` after every call to `br.write(dataWithNewLine);` (inside the loop).

A more concise alternative would be to use a [`PrintWriter` with auto-flush](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.Writer-boolean-):

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fr, true);
```

You can write to this with `println`, just as with `System.out`, and it will flush every time.

This also means you wouldn't have to worry about appending the newline character explicitly.